# WooCommerce custom variable product type (Out of Stock issue)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have already searched for the solution and got nothing in this regard.

In Woocommerce, I am registering a custom product type (giftcard) which extends `WC_PRODUCT_VARIABLE` and then I set attributes, variations and inventory tabs to be shown when the product type is of giftcard.

After that, I copied variable.php template to giftcard.php. The issue is that I am not getting the variations shown on the frontend.

It is always saying:

> This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.

Product Type Setup:

```
add_filter('product_type_selector', 'knlShopCreateGiftcardProductType');
function knlShopCreateGiftcardProductType($types) {
    $types['knl_shop_giftcard'] = __('Gift Card', 'knl-shop');
    return $types;
}

add_action('init', 'knlShopGiftcardProductTypeClass');
function knlShopGiftcardProductTypeClass() {
    require_once KNL_SHOP_INC . '/class-knlshop-wc-giftcard-prod-type.php';
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_class', 'knlShopInitGiftcardProductTypeClass', 10, 2);
function knlShopInitGiftcardProductTypeClass( $classname, $product_type ) {
    if ( $product_type == 'knl_shop_giftcard' ) {
        $classname = 'KNL_SHOP_WC_GIFTCARD_PROD_TYPE';
    }
    return $classname;
}

add_action('admin_footer', 'knlShopGiftcardProductTypeDataTabs');
function knlShopGiftcardProductTypeDataTabs() {
if('product' != get_post_type()) :
    return;
endif;
?>
<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
      
jQuery('.enable_variation').addClass('show_if_knl_shop_giftcard').show();
            jQuery('.inventory_options').addClass('show_if_knl_shop_giftcard').show();
jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._manage_stock_field').addClass('show_if_knl_shop_giftcard').show();
jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').parent().addClass('show_if_knl_shop_giftcard').show();
jQuery('#inventory_product_data ._sold_individually_field').addClass('show_if_knl_shop_giftcard').show();
        });
</script>
<?php

}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'knlShopAddProductDataTabsForGiftcard', 10, 1);
function knlShopAddProductDataTabsForGiftcard($tabs) {
    array_push($tabs['attribute']['class'], 'show_if_variable show_if_knl_shop_giftcard');
    array_push($tabs['variations']['class'], 'show_if_knl_shop_giftcard');
    array_push($tabs['inventory']['class'], 'show_if_knl_shop_giftcard');
    //array_push($tabs['general']['class'], 'show_if_knl_shop_giftcard');

    return $tabs;
}

add_action('woocommerce_knl_shop_giftcard_add_to_cart',  'knl_shop_giftcard_add_to_cart');
function knl_shop_giftcard_add_to_cart() {
wc_get_template('single-product/add-to-cart/giftcard.php', $args = array(), $template_path = '', KNL_SHOP_PATH . '/woocommerce/');
}
```

> giftcard.php is a copy of variable.php

And then my custom product class is as follows:

```
class KNL_SHOP_WC_GIFTCARD_PROD_TYPE extends WC_Product_Variable {
    public function __construct( $product = 0 ) {
        parent::__construct( $product );
    }

    public function get_type() {
        return 'knl_shop_giftcard';
    }
}
```

Now, when I create the giftcard product, i can see all the attributes and variations in the product edit page. But on frontend, single page gives the above mentioned error that its out of stock.

> On checking the values of **$attributes** and
> **$available_variations**, i get either empty or null.

I hope, I have explained my question well. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your question is not answerable as it requires debugging details: *"The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem**."* See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I don't think so that I have missed anything in my query. All I need to know is I am getting the mentioned error even after I set variation prices and stock.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i hope the required query details are now provided well. If possible, have a look and let me know if you can help in this

Comment: Did you end up finding why the variations were not being picked up? I am currently stuck on this and couldn't find the solution anywhere...

Comment: @BurninatorDor, nopes

Comment: See the answer about Data Store. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You **need to define the Data Store class for the new custom product type**. To do this, use the filter woocommerce_data_stores:

```
    /**
     * Defines Data Store Class for new custom product type
     * @param array $stores
     * @return array
     */
    function your_function( $stores ) {
        $stores['product-knl_shop_giftcard] = 'WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT';
        return $stores;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_data_stores', 'your_function', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: I also added `WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT` for the product variation.